# Unit Test on MVC 3 Controller returns null for results, but I can see them in Immediate Window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I am new to MVC and Unit Test. I am using Visual Studio unit test framework to test a product controller. The controller works on actual website but it always returns null in Unit Test. I have switch around keyword such as ViewResult or name of Model but all of them doesn't work because controller always return null. Then I put breaking point and start debug the testing code. When I test it in Immediate Window it has value.

What am I missing here?

I have a screenshot on this URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um2Ec.png
In screenshot you can see the Immediate Window the model is passed from controller successful, P4 P5 is stored in result. It just not work in UnitTest.

The List code is quite simple, It works fine on website. here is the code

```
    public int PageSize = 4;
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List(int page=1)
    {
        ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize).AsEnumerable(),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
            }
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: I think it would help to post your `ProductController.List` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had this problem before, you are not using the same versions of System.Web.Mvc in your projects. You must reference the same version of System.Web.Mvc both in your main project and unit test project.

Comment: thanks a ton Arvand.. i struggled with this problem. cant even think that a dll version mismatch cud be there. thanks again, it worked like charm. How did you figure the solution out ?

Comment: I had two projects one was apress source code (the example for MVC pro) second was my own project. The source code was working, my project didn't! since the codes were exactly the same I guessed it had to do with references.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your unit test you call the controller action twice... this could be having some unintended consequences?

How about trying:

```
//Action
ProductionsListViewModel result = (ProductsListViewModel)controller.List(2).Model;
Product prod = result.Products.ToArray();
```

Comment: I am doing the test. I am trying if that problem of cast or not. but both result is null.  
[code]Product prod = result.Products.ToArray();[/code]
prod must be array so this doesn't work.  
The problem is the result is already null. the rest of part would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still having the same issue, IntelliSense generated ActionResult instead of ViewResult in the controller for me when I typed in the code and somehow I missed the return type. Took me a couple of hours to notice the error. Now unit test passed like a charm